# What causes this error with Git and a locked ReSharper folder?

Tags: visual-studio, git, resharper, visual-studio-2012

I have received this error several times in recent months, but have not always received it. I suspect it appeared when I upgraded to VS11 Beta, or maybe ReSharper 7. When I try and add files from a new solution to a new Git repo, I occasionally get an error like the one below. What could be causing this?

```
error: open("_ReSharper.Avis/PersistentCaches/LOCK"): Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `LOCK` files are just markers used by different software to mark that something is in use, or to implement a form of critical section that should only allow one instance of a program to work with some data. And to have a secure lock, only one program should be allowed to touch such a file.

Git tries to check each file in the working tree to see if it differs from the index or not. And to do that, it must access these files, something that's not allowed for locked `LOCK` files.

Given that these files are not actual data files, they should be safely ignored. Try to [ignore all LOCK files](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/19/ignoring-files.html) in your repository.

Comment: Good point thanks. I currently just use Unlocker to kill all locks, but that fudges any hope of automating things. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

It's internal ReSharper's lock.
You should ignore ReSharper's caches folder _ReSharper.Avis and don't put it in VCS.